# mule 3.4 quartz endpoint not triggered

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, mule-esb

I want to trigger a flow using Quartz in a specific time in the day. The problem is that the flow is not triggered using mule 3.4 standalone server but it runs on mule 3.7 and 'hello' is printed each 2 seconds.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" 
      xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
      xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" 
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
      xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">
  <quartz:connector name="quartz_connector" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Quartz"/>
  <quartz:endpoint name="QUARTZ_ENDPOINT_NAME" jobName="name" 
                   cronExpression="*/2 * * * * ?" repeatInterval="0" 
                   responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="quartz_connector" 
                   doc:name="Scheduler">
    <quartz:event-generator-job/>
  </quartz:endpoint>
  <flow name="some_flow" doc:name="some_flow">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="QUARTZ_ENDPOINT_NAME" doc:name="QUARTZ_ENDPOINT_NAME_DOC"/>
    <flow-ref name="test-flow"/>
  </flow>
  <flow name="test-flow">
    <logger message="hello" level="INFO" doc:name="logger"/>
  </flow>
</mule>
```

Is there an issue of Quartz with mule 3.4? is there any alternatives i can use to achieve same goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Poll Component` as a alternative to Quartz.

Not sure poll in 3.4. Please check.

Regarding to Quartz - in 3.4 it should work. May be schema below for 3.7 dont work for 3.4

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd

In order to make sure. Create new - drop and drop the quartz in 3.4 freshly and reconfigure details.